# Как записать данные в переменную,которая находиться в redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

У меня есть такой метод getPostById, который делает асинхронный запрос и возвращает нам пост по которому мы кликнули. Как правильно создать переменную в редаксе article и в нее записывать данные, которые пришли от `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`?

```
    getPostById = async(id: any) => {
    const myResponse = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`);
    const myJson = await myResponse.json();
    const IWantToRedux = myJson.body
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({type: GET_ID, payload: IWantToRedux});
    }
}
```

мои actions

```
export const GET_ID = 'GET_ID'

export const getPostById = (changedBody: any) => ({
    type: GET_ID,
    payload: changedBody,
});
```

мой reducer

```
const initialState = {
        background: "blue",
        changedBody: 'hello',
    }
export function pageReducer(state = initialState, action: any) {
    switch (action.type) {

        case GET_ID:
            return {...state, getPostByIdAction: action.payload};
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, в чем ваша проблема. У вас же уже есть action `getPostById`, вот его и вызывайте в вашем методе. Правда у них имена совпадают, так что action придется переименовать, либо импорт-ть под другим именем.

Comment: @hindmost подскажите, как правильно вызвать этот action в обычном методе

Comment: Ну как-то так: `store.dispatch(getPostById(myJson.body))`. Но если внутри компонента, то лучше вызывать через пропсы из [`mapDispatchToProps`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect)

Comment: Да, насчет переименования это я немного погорячился. Если это метод класса, то переименовывать не нужно.